# Windows 7 shows blue screens and virus popups

Tags: windows-7, netbook

My netbook that I'm using now doesn't have a desktop anymore and I can't use the browser now because of the anti-virus pop up that advertises me to purchase something "premium". Then I clicked "buy" and my browser opened a popup.

What I can only see is a blue screen all over my LCD, and my cursor. What do you think is the problem?  And how can I fix this without reformatting my netbook, because I have my thesis files here?

I can't even see my start button and taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a really bad Virus.

I would go buy two flash drives. Install a [linux live disc](http://livecdlist.com/) on one, boot into that on your netbook (to mitigate the risk of virus spreading) and copy your thesis (and other important files) to the other one.

Then do extensive scans with

- [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)
- [Kaspersky](https://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk)
- [AVG](http://www.avg.com/us-en/avg-rescue-cd)

If that fails and you still see symptoms, then reformat.  Generally with these types of viruses, it's easier to reformat than rid yourself of all that... But that's up to you I guess.

Oh, and change your credit card number if you tried to actually buy anything...